# JavaScript Date Validation Function

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain how does the foll JS function validate date which needs to be of the form mm/dd/yyyy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkdate(input){
    var validformat=/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ //Basic check for format validity
    var returnval=false
    if (!validformat.test(input.value))
        alert("Invalid Date Format. Please correct and submit again.")
    else{ //Detailed check for valid date ranges
        var monthfield=input.value.split("/")[0]
        var dayfield=input.value.split("/")[1]
        var yearfield=input.value.split("/")[2]
        var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield-1, dayfield)
        if ((dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)||(dayobj.getDate()!=dayfield)||(dayobj.getFullYear()!=yearfield))
            alert("Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again.")
        else
            returnval=true
    }
    if (returnval==false) input.select()
        return returnval
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory. What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: I want to know whats going on after we construct the date object.

Comment: Is `(dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)` confusing you?

Comment: +1 a realy easy nice way of validating Date thanx

Comment: "too localized"... i don't knew that too localized was a a reason to close a question. Anyway, i read the answer, an it helps me!. Thanks to all except to x3ro, kazanaki, bažmegakapa, Linger, Justin Satyr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part uses regex to check if the value is in the required format `mm/dd/yyyy`. This is ensure that validation fails if it not a `/` delimited string with 2, 2 and 4 numbers respectively.

The second part creates a date object using the individual `dd`, `mm` and `yyyy` values and checks the properties of the created object with the original values in the input. This is to ensure that the validation fails for values like `02/31/2015`

`if ((dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)||(dayobj.getDate()!=dayfield)||(dayobj.getFullYear()!=yearfield))`

The above statement is to ensure that the created object reflects the same values that were used for creating it. Also, note that month index starts at `0`, hence the `-1` during creation and `+1` during checking.

Comment: Can you explain whats going on after we construct the date object